# Quais são os estados de um thread?

Tags: java, thread, concorrência

Andei pesquisando em alguns lugares da internet mas não encontrei coerências nas definições dadas sobre o assunto de *thread* em Java.

Quais são os estados possíveis de uma *thread* e quais são suas definições.

Comment: Depois que já tinha resposta fica complicado mudar o contexto da pergunta :/

Comment: @Renan obrigado pela atenção de qualquer forma!

Answer (score 13):

Se for específico para Java é fácil descobrir já que os estados são definidos por uma enumeração, então tem todos na [documentação da `Thread.State`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.State.html).

- NEW - ela foi criada e está pronta para iniciar (`start()`)
- RUNNABLE - ela está rodando (não existe o estado `RUNNING`)
- BLOCKED - ela está travada, em geral por `Lock` ou alguma operação de IO
- WAITING - ela está aguardando outra *thread* para rodar
- TIMED_WAITING - a mesma coisa, mas há um limite de tempo que ela esperará
- TERMINATED - ela terminou a execução, mas ainda existe (não existe o estado `DEAD`)

Não vai variar muito disto, mas outras implementações podem usar outro conjunto de estados.

Note que as incoerências encontradas provavelmente se dão porque as pessoas estão falando de coisas diferentes. Eu fico com a documentação, certamente não está errada. Quando encontra incoerência sempre vá no que é oficial.

Se não estiver falando de Java os estados pode variar. Cada plataforma pode ter seu próprio controle, inclusive diferente do sistema operacional. Se tiver curiosidade veja os [estados de *threads* possíveis em C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.threadstate?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 11):

### **Estados de uma thread**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Imagem retirada de [Thread States and Life Cycle](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/javatm-se-8/9780133891522/ch20lev1sec2.html).

Os estados, segundo a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html) são:

- **NEW**: Quando a `thread` é criada, porém não invocaram o `start()` na referência.
- **RUNNABLE** : Quando volta de algum estado, ou quando foi invocada o `start()` na referência.
- **BLOCKED**:

  1. Uma `thread` é considerada no estado *BLOCKED* quando está esperando dados.
  2. Uma `thread` também é considerada *BLOCKED* quando está aguardando a `Lock` de outra thread.
- **WAITING**: Uma `thread` que está esperando indefinidamente por outra thread para executar uma determinada ação está neste estado.
- **TIMED_WAITING**: Uma `thread` que está esperando por outro thread para executar uma ação por até um tempo de espera especificado está neste estado.
- **TERMINATED**: Uma `thread` que saiu está neste estado.

Para saber os estados, no `Java` você pode usar o método `Thread.getState` que retorna:

- NEW
- RUNNABLE
- BLOCKED
- WAITING
- TIMED_WAITING
- TERMINATED

Além do mais, pode-se chamar `isAlive()`

- `TRUE` significa que a thread está no estado *Runnable* ou no estado *Non-Runnable*.

Referências:

- [Documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html)