# Relação de threads com a quantidade de processadores

Tags: thread, multithreading, paralelismo

Na imagem abaixo do meu gerenciador de tarefas existem 3058 Threads. Meu processador possui 4 threads. Isso significa que dessas 3058 ele vai executar de 4 em 4 threads?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu processador possui 4 núcleos e 4 threads, isso significa que pra cada núcleo ele possui 4 threads?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não é tão simples assim. Isso significa que seu computar tem capacidade de executar 4 *threads* (é o número de processadores lógicos indicados) de cada vez em paralelo, ou seja, ao mesmo tempo de verdade.

Não quer dizer que porque tem tantas assim estará executando sempre 4, por diversas razões pode ter processadores não utilizados. O maior motivo para isso é uma *thread* estar parada e não precisa executar algo no momento, a maioria dessas que está mostrando aí estão em [estado de espera](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/157074/101) então pode não ter que executar 4 ao mesmo tempo.

É comum que várias delas que estão efetivamente rodando funcionarem mais ou menos ao mesmo tempo. Esse mais ou menos quer dizer que a execução [não é paralela, mas simultânea](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/166032/101). Elas vão executando aos poucos intercalando com outras. E claro que algumas serão simultâneas e paralelas, mas sempre no limite de 4 efetivamente paralelas. [Veja as diferenças](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157435/101).

Veja mais em [Existe diferença entre Programa, Thread e Processo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/131108/101) e [É sempre garantido que uma aplicação com múltiplas threads rode mais rápido que usando uma única thread?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1946/101).

Cada núcleo pode rodar uma única *thread* ao mesmo tempo. Alguns processadores permitem que um núcleo seja dividido em duas linhas de processamento e aí rodar duas *threads* ao mesmo tempo, mas isso não é tão ao mesmo tempo assim, há uma divisão dentro do hardware, mas não é exposto para o software, então funciona como se fosse ao mesmo tempo. Esses computadores mostrariam 8 processadores lógicos em vez de 4, mas ainda 4 núcleos, então conseguiria rodar 8 *threads* ao "mesmo tempo".

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).